# How to print from PDF to Thermal Printer

Tags: printer

I bought an Epson  TM-T88V to print out receipts from my web app.
Our app displays the receipts in a PDF file 2 inches wide and 6 inches tall.
However it looks like receipt printers like the Epson's TM-T88V are not designed to be used like regular printers.

Any tips here? We have to print from PDF.

Comment: Did you try "Fit to Page"?

Comment: the printer is not even listed

Comment: So then install the driver.

Comment: Ignacio - I think u don't understand that this is not a normal type of printer. It's designed for specific POS Programs to use via api

Comment: So then what the heck is ["Advanced Printer Driver"](http://pos.epson.com/developers/techresdetails.htm?ProductPK=642) supposed to be?

Comment: this worked! thanks  Ignacio , please post it as an answer so i can mark it so

Comment: Done as requested by Ignacio. Please mark it as accepted/working so that this post does not get bumped to the front page (thathappens now and then with posts with no accepted answers).

Answer (score 4):

You will need to install one of the printer drivers from [Epson's Tech Resources site](http://pos.epson.com/developers/techresdetails.htm?ProductPK=642) in order for it to be seen as a normal printer.